# rviz window closes itself

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to visualize the simulated of particles in rviz using points. But in the middle of simulation process, the rviz is getting crash. It gives the following description of problem.

rviz: /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.0/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:252: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed.
Aborted

Can any one help? thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9961/rviz-window-closes-itself/) by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-05-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-05-16**:
I've seen a similar problem in gazebo when fiddling with the stepsize parameter.  "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed.

**Comment by [Ali Abdul Khaliq](https://answers.ros.org/users/414/ali-abdul-khaliq/) on 2011-05-16**:
The resolution and rviz window size is fine. I just noticed that with other simulation display, the rviz is working fine but with the points simulation it gives the error. Can it be something wrong with the point simulation?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-15**:
I've seen this before but I can't quite recall in what cases... are you running the window under a weird resolution or making the rviz window very small/oddly sized?

**Comment by [Dannis Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31279/dannis-lee/) on 2017-07-20**:
I also come across the same problem these days, can you tell me how to fix it? thanks.

**Comment by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on 2017-08-09**:
I just had this when publishing an incomplete odometry-orientation and opened a bug report on [github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1137).

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2020-04-11**:
Happened to me too when I was accidentally publishing messages with illegal values, in my case NaNs in a PoseStamped. Once I made sure there were no NaNs in the message, the error no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can provide minimal code to reproduce this, you should file a bug.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got this error message and checked my cloud for strange points. My problem were points with huge values (z of 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000).
This nice number can also be written as (2^24-1)*2^104, which happens to be max_float, so I guess I made a mistake at recognizing nans.

The data came from the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [NikolasEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/652/nikolasengelhard/) with karma: 106 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3